# ffmpeg h.246 plays locally in Safari, but not when hosted on s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, ffmpeg, safari, mp4

ffmpeg h.246 plays locally in Safari, but not when hosted on s3 bucket.

I thought it was therefore a problem with S3, however a friend has sent me an `.mp4` of the same file converted with [Zencoder](https://zencoder.com/en/)'s service and this works perfectly, which surely means it must be a problem with my encoding settings in ffmpeg?

I'm using the settings recommended for maximum compatibility:

`ffmpeg -an -i mov-input-02.mov -vcodec libx264 -filter:v scale="1400:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline mov-output-02-1400.mp4`

Additionally, the `.webm` files I'm converting with ffmpeg all work perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc.!

I would really appreciate any thoughts.

The video that works from Zencoder has this metadata:

```
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 1
compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
creation_time   : 2018-06-01T11:24:54.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:10.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 396 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1800x1200 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 394 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-06-01T11:24:49.000000Z
```

While my videos from ffmpeg which don't work have this metadata:

```
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
Duration: 00:00:10.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 184 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1400x932 [SAR 699:700 DAR 3:2], 182 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
  timecode        : 00:00:00:01
Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
  timecode        : 00:00:00:01
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
```

Here's the full output from conversion:

```
    Tempuras-iMac:2018.06.05 tempura$ ffmpeg -an -i mov-input-01.mov -vcodec l      Tempuras-iMac:2018.06.05 tempura$ ffmpeg -an -i mov-input-02.mov -vcodec libx264 -filter:v scale="1400:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 mov-output-02-1400.mp4 
    ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
      libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
      libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
      libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
      libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
      libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
      libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
      libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
      libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'mov-input-02.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2018-05-09T09:59:58.000000Z
      Duration: 00:00:10.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 114375 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24(progressive), 2700x1800, 113610 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-05-09T09:59:58.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Animation
          timecode        : 00:00:00:01
        Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-05-09T09:59:58.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          timecode        : 00:00:00:01
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (qtrle (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] using SAR=699/700
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] frame MB size (88x59) > level limit (1620)
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] MB rate (155760) > level limit (40500)
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to 'mov-output-02-1400.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1400x932 [SAR 699:700 DAR 3:2], q=-1--1, 0.03 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-05-09T09:59:58.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          timecode        : 00:00:00:01
          encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    [mp4 @ 0x7fac39003000] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file     
    frame=  329 fps= 42 q=-1.0 Lsize=     248kB time=00:00:10.93 bitrate= 185.5kbits/s speed= 1.4x    
    video:245kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.042892%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] frame I:2     Avg QP:15.82  size: 34370
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] frame P:327   Avg QP:16.88  size:   555
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] mb I  I16..4: 76.8%  0.0% 23.2%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] mb P  I16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.2%  P16..4:  0.7%  0.2%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.3%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 14.3% 0.1% 0.1% inter: 0.2% 0.0% 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 57% 39%  3%  0%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 24% 20%  2%  3%  3%  2%  3%  1%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
    [libx264 @ 0x7fac39004200] kb/s:182.53
```

Comment: Add `-movflags +faststart`

Comment: Thanks @Gyan – I have done this (and forgot to mention had tried in the past) – but still makes no difference.

Edited question to include in code.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: @Gyan updated my post with ffprobe data on the video that does work and the video that doesn't

Comment: The forced level seems suspect. Remove that.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the forced level but it still doesn't load the video @Gyan